# how to identify that anystring of list contains digits or not in python

Tags: python

I want to identify whether any string of the list contain number/ digit at any position, and if so then code should remove that digit from the string by use of python. My code is

```
pattern = '\w+-\w+[-\w+]*|-';
pattern2 = '\d'
contents = ["babies","walked","boys","walking", "CD28", "IL-2", "honour"];
for token in contents:
    if token.endswith("ies"):
        f.write(string.replace(token,'ies','y',1))
    elif token.endswith('s'):
        f.write(token[0:-1])
    elif token.endswith("ed"):
        f.write(token[0:-2])
    elif token.endswith("ing"):
        f.write(token[0:-3])
    elif re.match(pattern,token):
        f.write(string.replace(token,'-',""))
    elif re.match(pattern2,token):
        f.write(token.translate(None,"0123456789"))
    else:
       f.write(t)
f.close()
```

actually the problem is in `re.match(patter2,token)`. It does not identify a digit in token but `f.write(token.translate(None,"0123456789"))` worked well when I used it alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `re.sub` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> contents = ["IL-2", "CD-28","IL2","25"]
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r'\d','',i) for i in contents]
['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '']
```

But as a better solution for such task you can use `str.translate` method!

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> [i.translate(None,digits) for i in contents]
['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '']
```

And if you are in python 3 :

```
>>> trans_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord,digits), None)
>>> [i.translate(trans_table) for i in contents]
['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '']
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham before you answer i have been editing my answer! also i have mentioned `str.translate`! i always mentioned this for such problems!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes i saw your answer but after myself's answer ,any way  you get my up vote too!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove digits use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
contents = ["IL-2", "CD-28","IL2","25"];

print([s.translate(None,"0123456789") for s in contents])
['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '']
```

If you only want to remove the digits if the string contains a mixture:

```
print([s.translate(None,"0123456789") if not s.isdigit() else s for s in contents])
  ['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '25']
```

If the digits are always at the end you can use rstrip:

```
print([s.rstrip("0123456789") for s in contents])
```

For python 3 you need to create a table using [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans):

```
tbl = str.maketrans({k:"" for k in dig})


print([s.translate(tbl) for s in contents])
['IL-', 'CD-', 'IL', '']
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74272/discussion-on-answer-by-padraic-cunningham-how-to-identify-that-anystring-of-lis).

Answer (score 0):

```
import nltk;
import string;
import re;
f=open("stemming.txt",'w')
contents=file.read();
pattern = '\w+-\w+[-\w+]*|-';
digits = re.compile('\d')
contents = ["babies","walked","boys","walking", "CD28", "IL-2", "honour"];
for token in contents:
    if token.endswith("ies"):
        f.write(string.replace(token,'ies','y',1))
    elif token.endswith('s'):
        f.write(token[0:-1])
    elif token.endswith("ed"):
        f.write(token[0:-2])
    elif token.endswith("ing"):
        f.write(token[0:-3])
    elif re.match(pattern,token):
        f.write(string.replace(token,'-',""))
    elif bool(digits.search(token)):
        f.write(token.translate(None,"0123456789"))
    else:
        f.write(t)
f.close()
```